# How to understand jHipster frontend parts?

Tags: jhipster

I've never had anything to do with AngularJS or any frontend technologies, so it's hard for me to grasp. I have a jHipster project that I need to customize and turn into a useful thing. How it looks doesn't matter for now, it needs to work. I watched the "jHipster in 20 minutes" video and even read the minibook, but these didn't help me understand how to deal with the generated files. 
I need some guidelines and explanation on how files like entities/entity1/entity1.controller.js, entity1.service.js and entity1.state.js are dependent on each other (and on Java Spring @Services/@Controllers/ Spring Data entities in general). What's the procedure to add new functionalities (views, dialogs)?

Answer (score 0):

In short.

Controller: decorator of the entity
Entity: is what backend(spring boot) gives you
Service: used to make calls to the backend to get the entity data.

State: ->  uses the service -> uses the "Backend" to get Entity data
and sets the Entity on the Controller

Comment: In other words:
state.js makes a call to service.js to get entity data from the backend (Entity.java) and then passes this data to controller.js? 
If my website is to be simple, do I have to mess with service.js and controller.js at all?
Where do I make calls to Spring @Services to perform business logic?

Comment: if your website is simple , we still need this framework

Comment: if your website is simple , we still need this framework since it clearly separates the responsibilities (MVC). your service can make calls to backend service to perform business logic.